# $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{z^{2n}}{n2^n} =$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I already know it converge if $|z| < \sqrt2$ , 
but how can i calculate the sum in that range ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{z^{2n}}{n2^n} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{z^2}{2}\right)^n = -\log\left(1 - \frac{z^2}{2}\right).$$

The last step follows from the identiy

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} = -\log(1 - x), \quad |x| < 1$$